# River altitude by google elevation - bottom or surface?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

guys,

I’m developing a web application that uses Google Elevation, and now I wanna get a river altitude..
Does anybody know if the altitude that Elevation returns is from river bottom or surface?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking an example from a lake, it would be the top. However to prove this, you would need to find the elevation along a path across a very deep river.

[image: Lake Chelan elevation]

This is the elevation along a path that crosses Lake Chelan which is over 1400 feet deep.